# How to resolve a path that includes an environment variable, in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

I would like to run an executable and its path contains an enviroment variable, for example if I would like to run chrome.exe I would like to write something like this

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
spawn('chrome',[], {cwd: '%LOCALAPPDATA%\\Google\\Chrome\\Application', env: process.env})
```

instead of

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
spawn('chrome',[], {cwd: 'C:\\Users\myuser\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application', env: process.env}).
```

Is there a package I can use in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These answers are crazy. Just can use `path`:

```js
const folder = require('path').join(
    process.env.LOCALAPPDATA,
    'Google/Chrome/Application',
);

console.log(folder); // C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application
```

Comment: Note that the environment variable is hard-coded in your solution. Other answers are not crazy since they take into account paths read from configurations or other input. In this case though, your solution has apparently been sufficient.

Answer (score 20):

You can use a regex to replace your variable with the relevant property of [`process.env`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) :

```
let str = '%LOCALAPPDATA%\\Google\\Chrome\\Application'
let replaced = str.replace(/%([^%]+)%/g, (_,n) => process.env[n])
```

I don't think a package is needed when it's a one-liner.

Comment: ok I can use this, I just thought there was some built-in util for this.

Comment: I get that it's short and straight to the point. But this leads people to blindly copy-pasting solutions that only make sense in the moment and will bug everyone after that. See Jaredcheeda's for something more likely to be understood later.

Answer (score 4):

I realize that the question is asking for Windows environment variables, but I modified @Denys Séguret's answer to handle bash's `${MY_VAR}` and `$MY_VAR` style formats as I thought it might be useful for others who came here.

Note: the two arguments are because there are two groupings based on the variations of the format.

```
str.replace(/\$([A-Z_]+[A-Z0-9_]*)|\${([A-Z0-9_]*)}/ig, (_, a, b) => process.env[a || b])
```

Comment: I wish I could give you a bounty for this, saved me a ton of time!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a generic helper function for this:

```js
/**
 * Replaces all environment variables with their actual value.
 * Keeps intact non-environment variables using '%'
 * @param  {string} filePath The input file path with percents
 * @return {string}          The resolved file path
 */
function resolveWindowsEnvironmentVariables (filePath) {
  if (!filePath || typeof(filePath) !== 'string') {
    return '';
  }

  /**
   * @param  {string} withPercents    '%USERNAME%'
   * @param  {string} withoutPercents 'USERNAME'
   * @return {string}
   */
  function replaceEnvironmentVariable (withPercents, withoutPercents) {
    let found = process.env[withoutPercents];
    // 'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%asdf%' => 'C:\Users\bob\Desktop\%asdf%'
    return found || withPercents;
  }

  // 'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%' => 'C:\Users\bob\Desktop\AMD64'
  filePath = filePath.replace(/%([^%]+)%/g, replaceEnvironmentVariable);

  return filePath;
}
```

- Can be called from anywhere
- Does basic type checking first, you may want to change what is returned by default in the first `if` block
- Functions are named in ways that explain what they do
- Variables are named in ways that explain what they are
- Comments added make it clear what outcomes can occur
- Handles non-environment variables wrapped in percents, since the Windows file system allows for folders to be named `%asdf%`
- JSDoc blocks for automated documentation, type checking, and auto-complete in certain editors
- You may also want to use `if (process.platform !== 'win32') {}` depending on your need

Comment: +1 for readability and explanations. Far more maintainable than Denys Séguret's answer. The (perceived) added complexity is totally negligible in comparison. People should prefer this over one-liners that have too much specificity and make no sense after you've written and left them behind.

Comment: Really nice & short! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a TypeScript friendly addition to the excellent answer by Denys Séguret:

```
let replaced = str.replace(/%([^%]+)%/g, (original, matched) => {
      const r = Process.env[matched]
      return r ? r : ''
})
```

Answer (score -1):

On Linux/MacOS, I spawn a process to resolve paths with env variables, is safe - let bash to do the work for you. Obviously less performant, but a lot more robust. Looks like this:

```
import * as cp from 'child_process';

// mapPaths takes an array of paths/strings with env vars, and expands each one

export const mapPaths = (searchRoots: Array<string>, cb: Function) => {

  const mappedRoots = searchRoots.map(function (v) {
    return `echo "${v}"`;
  });

  const k = cp.spawn('bash');

  k.stdin.end(mappedRoots.join(';'));
  const results: Array<string> = [];
  k.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);

  k.stdout.on('data', (d: string) => {
    results.push(d);
  });

  k.once('error',  (e) => {
    log.error(e.stack || e);
    cb(e);
  });

  k.once('exit', code => {

    const pths = results.map((d) => {
      return String(d || '').trim();
    })
    .filter(Boolean);

    cb(code, pths);

  });
};
```

Comment: Can you please precise how it is more robust?

Comment: I imagine he means it's robust in the way that it will expand things the exact same way that bash does (because it's bash doing it, however, it's less robust in another way because your application now depends on the existence of bash.